# Can there be more than one VBA project open at the same time?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a VBA project provided by my company. It is password protected and I cannot add new modules to the project nor can I have a second one open at the same time.

Could I either remove the password from that VBA project, have a second project open at the same time, or still run my own custom macros at the same time?

I basically want to use the company macros as well as my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have multiple VBA projects opened at the same time. But you can have multiple modules opened, imported and exported. So, following that way with modules you can have both solutions working in Outlook.

As I already wrote, Outlook support only one VBA project at a time. On the other hand, one can select, which of all possible VBA projects should be used at start. VBA project is saved in separated OTM file, located at `%appdata%\Microsoft\Outlook`.

To start other VBA project than default, one has to enable this option, a corresponding registry value is listed below:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Security\EnableAltVba`

It has to be set to 1) and then after Outlook can be started with command line switch

`Outlook.exe /altvba \\MyServer\MyShare\otmfilename.otm`

Comment: I was able to find a backup of the VBA project without password protection. Thank you for the information!